# VS 2010 - How can build MSI to deploy an assembly that is in my GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2010 (C#) and have a 3rd party assembly (dll) dependency that is required for my MSI build to work. I've added it as a reference to the relevant project. However, the dll file has been put into the GAC. So, it won't copy local and is excluded from my build. I wrote a post-build script to copy it to the output folder but it still doesn't get included. Is there any way to get this assembly into my build so I can get it installed on client PCs?

Comment: something like: right click the component, build properties -> `copy always` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a post-build script you could unfold the references-node of you VS-project, go to the assembly which is in the GAC, (right-click > properties) and set the 'Copy Local' property to 'True'. 
If you do this, the assembly will be copied in the Output-folder on builden the project.

In the Setup-project, you can then right-click this project > 'Add' > 'Project Output..'

 
This should get the job done of adding the dll to the installer.

If this didn't work, you can also right-click the setup-project > 'Add' > 'Assembly', followed by selecting the assembly you want to be added to your installer. This way it will definitely be added to the installer and end up in the e.g. %Drive%:\Program Files\InstallFolder

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd option seems to have worked. I need to try on a test client first.